# Bootstrap 4 tabs multi-level tablist with collapse is not working properly; more than one tab active at the same time

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
  li.nav-item {  display: block;  width: 100%;  position: relative;  display: lock;  min-height: 40px;  line-height: 2.4;  padding: 0;  color: #f0f0f0;  font-weight: 600;  font-size: 16px;  border-bottom: 1px solid #092a3b;  background: #233d4a;  margin: 0;
}

a {
  display:block;
}

a.active {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">1</a>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#Menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" data-parent="#collapseOne">
                        <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#One1">1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-parent="#collapseOne">
                        <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#One2">1.2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" data-parent="#collapseOne">
                        <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#One3">1.3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"  data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">2</a>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#Menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#Two1">2.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#Two2">2.2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#Two3">2.3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#Three">3</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="" data-toggle="tab" href="#Four">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I am struggling to achieve a multi level tablist menu with collapsible sub menus with Bootstrap 4. I need to use tabs and collapse at the same time. I have achieved to make the functionality (the right panes appearing and disappearing clicking the right links) work properly but there are more than one tab with the active class at the same time. I would like to know if there´s a way to make it work properly just with bootstrap 4 classes not adding more js/jquery code.

Here´s my codepen:
https://codepen.io/AlbertoAguado/pen/XqdmbK

Answer (score 1):

The problem is combining tabs and collapse on the same parent level. Currently, 1&2 toggle tabs, and 3&4 toggle collapse. You need to make them all collapse with tabs inside (exactly like collapse 1&2), or make them all `collapse` items inside the `#Menu`.

Additionally, you need to hide any shown tabs when one of the collapse elements is hidden..

```
$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.tab-content .show').removeClass('show');
})
```

https://codeply.com/go/Aq4zWAcUkX

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, yes the problem is that the elements are not in the same level of the ul. But the solution that you offer doesn´t work. As you can see in the codeply that you have attached it´s possible to have more than one item with the class active at the same time. Thank you anyway!